# i need to make button loading... on click and at the same time before loading... check the validation required

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm writing a piece of HTML and JavaScript code, and I need to check if inputs have been filled before loading button after click on it. However, when I leave them blank, it proceeds to the PHP page passing the variables empty.

What I need is to add validation the forms to this code before loading button & disabled.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btnFetch").click(function() {
    // disable button
    $(this).prop("disabled", true);
    // add spinner to button
    $(this).html(
      '<i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin"></i> loading...'
    );
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi! It might help if you include the html code. Even more if you could create a jsfiddle for the whole thing.

Comment: Yes, this is form validation and there are thousands of tutorials and questions about this behavior online and on this site. Please [edit] your question to show what research you've done and what attempts you've made to solve the issue yourself. The current code does not show an attempt to solve; it just shows that you disable the button and show a spinner, no attempt to validate anything.

Comment: See [jquery validation plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/?__cf_chl_managed_tk__=pmd_mTdULQIb5U_bWgnh1BscV07MyOISHXkxzM7pYTcIjEk-1634643873-0-gqNtZGzNAtCjcnBszRHl).